# enforce WPF ContentControls to have maximum width

Tags: wpf, width, contentcontrol

I have ContentControls like ComboBox and TextBox inside of a Grid or a StackPanel. I want them to have the maximum possible width. How do I achieve that? I've noticed that Button has maximum width any way when it is added to a StackPanel, but ComboBox and TextBox do not. I've tried setting ContentControls' Width="*", but that doesn't work.

Comment: In a vertical StackPanel all child controls get the same width by default. If it is meant to be horizontal, do you want them to have all the same width? Then you should better use a Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"?